# Changing Text Size in Libchart

Tags: php, html, css

I am integrating Libchart (the free PHP Chart Library) into a simple APP for the purpose of drawing different types of graphs. I have been able to adapt it to use my data as well as changing the size of the generated Graph. I cant see where to change the text size.In Libchart, the size of the generated chart was not specified and the default was too small.

For Vertical Bar Chart I have the following code:

```
 echo"<br />";
    //include "libchart/classes/libchart.php";
    echo '<h3><b>Graph A</b></h3>';
    $chart = new VerticalBarChart(880,400);
    $dataSet = new XYDataSet();

    if (!empty($pass_percent_eng))$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("English", $pass_percent_eng));
    if (!empty($pass_percent_mat))$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Maths", $pass_percent_mat));
    if (!empty($pass_percent_che))$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Chemistry", $pass_percent_che));
    if (!empty($pass_percent_phy))$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Physics", $pass_percent_phy));
    if (!empty($pass_percent_bio))$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Biology", $pass_percent_bio));

    $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);
    $chart->setTitle("$school - Pass Percentage Grade $grade$class, Term $term, $year");

    $chart->render("generated/demo.png");
    echo '<img class="graph" alt="Vertical bars chart" src="generated/demo.png" style="border: 1px solid gray;"/>';
```

I added the length and width to the function $chart= new VerticalBarchart(880,400).

**Que**:

How do I adjust the font size (if possible, the font itself as well) for the Title Text and the text for the bars. I have checked all the scripts in Libchart but could not see anywhere to adjust text, it does not seem to have been set. My guess is may be it should be defined in the *chart script* itself since that is where the size of the bar graph is defined.

So far I tried Wrapping the whole thing in a div, and set text size to the class of the DIV via CSS. But I had no joy with that.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be too late to help but...

To change the font size you'd have to edit
libchart\classes\view\text\Text.php

line 63   $fontSize = 8; //change to another number

also line 115

Doesn't seem to be parameterised.

To change the font-face add the .tff files to the font folder and change these lines 39/40 to reference your fonts, I'm using PTS as below:

$this->fontCondensed = $baseDir . "fonts/PTS55F-webfont.ttf";

$this->fontCondensedBold = $baseDir . "fonts/PTS75F-webfont.ttf";

Hope this helps.